# Rails association has_one has inverse behavior than expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I just added a new model `Intent` to save informations about users that want to buy our products and services.

So I save in this table `intent` the id of `Product`, `Service` and `User`.

I created a migration to reference the foreign keys in Intent and then added the following associations

```
belongs_to :user
has_one :product
has_one :service
```

And I wanted Rails to search for `product_id` and `service_id` in Intent, but the opposite is happening:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'products.intent_id' in 'where clause':
>   ...

How do I fix it? Did I choose the wrong association type?

Comment: why not belongs_to product / service? why has_one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :service
```

And then have `has_many :intents` in `user.rb` and `has_one :intent` in `product.rb` and `service.rb`.

The way I remember `has_one` is that it replaces `has_many`, so you'd put it wherever you'd normally put `has_many`.